# i have a black screen when booting ubuntu 14.04 just after update on my samsung chromebook

Tags: 14.04, boot, reboot, chromebook

hey guys i got a problem i have spent day and night for the past week trying to install Ubuntu on a Samsung Chromebook which i plan to do an internal hardware makeover on but unfortunately right now i'm out of the money so my main goal as of now is to install Ubuntu the first half goes smooth and Ubuntu 12.04.5 boots up like a charm and all but its out dated and i prefer Ubuntu 14.04.1 and the upgrade goes alright but here is where it get tricky i reboot my system go back into developer mode and open a terminal and do my Ubuntu launch command and it takes me to a blank black screen so when i do my command to go back to chrome (p)OS and view my terminal i see this

chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension GLX
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi, removing from list!
/usr/bin/xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
^C
Session terminated, terminating shell.../usr/bin/xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down Hangup
Running exit commands...

/usr/bin/xinit: unexpected signal 2
 ...terminated.
Not unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise as another instance is using it.
chronos@localhost / $

what do i do to get pass this and to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade has not done properly so this might caused the issue. Please try with the below command,

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install linux-source

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo reboot

Comment: i did that and i still have ubuntu 12.04.5